# Lit-Element and Redux: Update Object in Array

Tags: javascript, redux, lit-element, lit-html

I am trying to update the `roll` property in an object which is nested in the `players` array.
My state looks like this:

```
players: [
  {
    "id": "44ufazeep0o",
    "name": "test-player-1",
    "roll": 0,
    "totalWins": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "eu8hutex7z9",
    "name": "test-player-2",
    "roll": 0,
    "totalWins": 0
  }
]
```

This is my `action`:

```
export const addRoll = (roll, id) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_ROLL,
    roll,
    id,
  }
}
```

This is my `reducer`:

```
case ADD_ROLL:
  return state.players.map((player) => {
    if (player.id === action.id) {
      return {
        ...player,
        roll: action.roll,
      }
    }
    return player;
  });
  ...
```

I am watching `state.players` in an components like so:

```
import { connect } from 'pwa-helpers'; // connects a Custom Element base class to the Redux store
...

stateChanged(state) {
   this.players = state.players;
}

render() {
  return html`${this.players.map((player)=> html`<h1>${player.name}</h1>`)}`
}
```

Now, whenever I call `store.dispatch(addRoll(this.roll, this.id))`, `this.players.map()` returns `undefined` in the component where I am watching `state.players`. 
Any input on why this might happen is much appreciated!

Comment: I guess the stateChanged method is never called. What is the result when you console.log the state in the stateChanged method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have return an array instead of an object with players key in it from state after ADD_ROLL action is dispatched. Correct way to update it would be

```
case ADD_ROLL:
  return {
    ...state,
    players: state.players.map((player) => {
      if (player.id === action.id) {
        return {
          ...player,
          roll: action.roll,
        }
      }
      return player;
    });
  }
  ...
```